# How to show sensor reading in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to capture readings from the sensor into tkniter and am stuck on a small problem.
To simulate sensor reading I created a small function that increments the number for 1 every second. And in this example, I am trying to present that counter within tkniter label.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter

# Setting up theme of GUI
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.is_on = True
        self.title("Cool Blue")
        self.geometry(f"{220}x{160}")
        self.temperature = tkinter.IntVar()

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # create frame for environmental variable
        self.temperature_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.temperature_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.temperature_frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.label_temperature = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame, text="Temperature")
        self.label_temperature.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")
        self.label_temperature_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame,
                                                              textvariable=self.temperature,
                                                              font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=50, weight="bold"))

        self.label_temperature_value.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")
        self.label_temperature_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame,
                                                              text = f'\N{DEGREE CELSIUS}',
                                                              font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))

        self.label_temperature_value.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=10, sticky="sw")

    def temp(self):
        import time
        i = 0
        while True:
            start = round(time.time(), 0)
            time.sleep(1)
            stop = round(time.time(), 0)
            j = stop - start
            i = i + j
            print(i)
        return i

        self.temperature = temp(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

If set my self.temperature.set(5) I see the 5 Celsius displayed within tkineter.
However, when I try dynamically feeding this variable using temp() function, I am not getting any numbers.

What I expect is to see 1, then 2, then 3 etc.

What am I doing wrong here?

thank you in advance.

PS. here is the example of my code for reading the data from the sensor:

```
import time
import board
from busio import I2C
import adafruit_bme680
import datetime
import adafruit_veml7700

i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
veml7700 = adafruit_veml7700.VEML7700(i2c)
# Create library object using our Bus I2C port
i2c = I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
bme680 = adafruit_bme680.Adafruit_BME680_I2C(i2c, debug=False)

while True:
    TEMPERATURE = round(bme680.temperature, 2)
    time. Sleep(1)
```

Comment: You have never called `temp()`.  Note that it is not recommended (or should not) using infinite loop in a tkinter GUI applicaton as it will block the tkinter `mainloop()` from handling pending events.  Either use thread to run the infinite loop or use `.after()` to replace the loop.

Comment: @acw1668 - thank you for your feedback. I tried adding the temp() under the app.mainloop just to test it out and I'm still not getting anything. Do you mind showing me the example with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update the temperature variable by calling `temperature.set(...)`,

Then you can use the `self.after(...)` method to update the variable at intervals of some fixed amount of time by calling the `self.temp()` function again.

At the bottom I included a dummy class that changes temperature to simulate getting a signal from external source.

Example:

```
import time
import tkinter
import customtkinter

# Setting up theme of GUI
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # configure window
        self.is_on = True
        self.title("Cool Blue")
        self.geometry(f"{220}x{160}")
        self.temperature = tkinter.IntVar()
        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        # create frame for environmental variable
        self.temperature_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.temperature_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.temperature_frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.label_temperature = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame, text="Temperature")
        self.label_temperature.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        self.label_temperature_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            master=self.temperature_frame, textvariable=self.temperature,
            font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=50, weight="bold"))
        self.label_temperature_value.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

        self.label_temperature_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            master=self.temperature_frame, text = f'\N{DEGREE CELSIUS}',
            font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
        self.label_temperature_value.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=10, sticky="sw")

        self.temp()  # call the temp function just once

    def temp(self):
        self.temperature.set(Temp.current()) 
        self.after(2000, self.temp)  # 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds

import random
class Temp:
    temp = random.randint(10,35)
    def current():
        diff = random.randint(-3,3)
        return Temp.temp + diff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you again for your explanation. I just added an example of my code that captures the temperature from the sensor. So basically what I need to do is take that while loop where I capture the temperature and implement it as the new class with the same logic you did with your random example. Correct?
And does it need to be a new class or i can have it as a function of the existing App class?

Comment: the Temp class is only there to simulate getting a constant measure from some source.  You should pretend like it's not even there.  Do whatever is most convenient for your own measurement implementation

Comment: thank you again for all your help. I was able to implement sensor reading based on your suggestion. I will post the final code for anyone else if they ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

With Alexander's help here, I was able to incorporate readings from BME680 sensor and project them into tknite GUI.
Here is the code if anyone encounters the same issue:

```
import time
import tkinter
import customtkinter

import time
import board
from busio import I2C
import adafruit_bme680

# Create library object using our Bus I2C port
i2c = I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
bme680 = adafruit_bme680.Adafruit_BME680_I2C(i2c, debug=False)

# Setting up theme of GUI
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # configure window
        self.is_on = True
        self.title("Cool Blue")
        self.geometry(f"{220}x{160}")
        self.temperature = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.pressure = tkinter.IntVar()
        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        # create frame for environmental variable
        self.temperature_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.temperature_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.temperature_frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.label_temperature = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame, text="Temperature")
        self.label_temperature.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        self.label_temperature_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame, textvariable=self.temperature,font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=50, weight="bold"))
        self.label_temperature_value.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

        self.label_temperature_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame, text = f'\N{DEGREE CELSIUS}',font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
        self.label_temperature_value.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=10, sticky="sw")


        self.pressure_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.pressure_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.pressure_frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.label_pressure = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.pressure_frame, text="Pressure")
        self.label_pressure.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        self.label_pressure_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.pressure_frame, textvariable=self.pressure,font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=50, weight="bold"))
        self.label_pressure_value.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

        self.label_pressure_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature_frame, text = f'\N{DEGREE CELSIUS}',font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
        self.label_pressure_value.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=10, sticky="sw")



        self.temp()  # call the temp function just once

    def temp(self):
        current_temp, current_pres,  = self.current()
        self.temperature.set(current_temp)
        self.pressure.set(current_pres)
        self.after(2000, self.temp)  # 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds

    def current(self):
            current_temp = round(bme680.temperature, 2)
            current_pres = round(bme680.pressure, 2)
            print(f'{current_temp}')
            return current_temp, current_pres

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: The while loop inside `current()` is not necessary since you called `return` inside the loop.

Comment: @acw1668 -  good point. I made an adjustment and republish the final code. Thank you